# CData ODBC driver and SQL Server Polybase

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc

I am currently testing External Tables in SQL Server 2019 using a the CData ODBC driver with a PostgreSQL database.

I've managed to connect via an external data source and create external tables.

I get the following error though when I select from a table containing a date:

> Generic ODBC error: Error parsing date value [30/01/2014 08:41:35.838]

The PostgreSQL database has that column as a timestamp and the SQL external table is using a datetime2.

I've tried altering the language settings for my login to SQL but this didn't solve the problem. Is there a setting on the ODBC driver that might fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with PostgreSQL driver? https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

I suspect if you enable logging in PostgreSQL you won't find anything, the problem may be in the ODBC; there is no debugging for it but you may contact the provider for support.

Comment: I've raised a support ticket with CData but they can't replicate the issue. Also I couldn't get the PostgreSQL driver to work with external data sources. Evend up using a linked server with the PostgreSQL driver

Comment: Once installed, you create the database scoped credential:
`CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Postgres] WITH
  IDENTITY='postgres',
  SECRET='@P0s7gr3sT3st'`
Then the external data source:
`CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [DS] WITH (
  LOCATION='odbc://192.168.1.3:5432',
  CONNECTION_OPTIONS='Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)};',
  CREDENTIAL=[Postgres])`
And finally the external table:
`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [PostgresTable] (
  [PrimaryKey] INT NOT NULL,
  [RandomInt] INT NOT NULL,
  [RandomFloat] REAL NOT NULL)
WITH (
  LOCATION='PostgresTable',
  DATA_SOURCE=[DS])`